# convert multiple whitespaces value to tab value for password storing

Tags: php, passwords, ascii

I dont know; may be it seems crazy or totally unprofessional newbie question. However is it good choice to convert four spaces to tab for a password field?

Here is what I want to do- whenever the user put password in the password field; I want to trim the left and right whitespace (if any)! and in the middle of string if user put four spaces convert it to TAB key value (or vice versa??) and then hash the value..

I want to mention that the password field will accept whitespace and the password field is not only restricted to English character set.

Is it good practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can discuss the trimming of the password, i myself think it is a good idea.

Altering the password although, wont give you any benefit and can even be harmful. Assuming that you are properly hashing passwords before storing them, you can see the alteration as just an additional part of the hashing algorithm. Whatever changes you make, the entropy of the password cannot be increased by an algorithm, the password cannot become any stronger. On the other side it can decrease the entropy. An easy example:

*The same password, once with 4 spaces, once with a single tab will result in the same hash-value.*

So go with trimmed passwords for convenience if you like, but leave the content of the password unaltered.

Answer (score 1):

Trimming the start and end is definitely good practice.

However converting whitespace characters to a tab would be a very bad idea.  How would the user be able to log in?  When they press the Tab button in the password box the browser will move the focus out of the password box to the next control on the page.  There is no way for them to be able to type a Tab into the password!

Leave any spaces in the middle of the password as they are.

Comment: Actually this is just an example. Just to strength the password. User will enter four spaces everytime. Just my login script compress that 4 spaces as a tab key value and store it; or another example could be if user uses a character 'e'; I will change that as '3'.. everytime my login check get the 'e' character, convert that as '3' and then compare the hashed value from db.

Comment: but (for example) if a user sets their password to 'hello' and you convert it to 'h3110' how will they know their password?

Answer (score -1):

great that you plan on removing the leading/trailing spaces, however I don't see a reason to change those spaces to tabs, since it's just an extra step before encrypting them.
If there's no good reason to put something in it's generally better to... not put it in
(edit: I'm assuming the same check would be in place on login)

(ps: this type of question isn't really fit for StackOverflow though since it involves personal opinions)

Comment: Actually this is just an example. Just to strength the password. User will enter four spaces everytime. Just my login script compress that 4 spaces as a tab key value and store it; or another example could be if user uses a character 'e'; I will change that as '3'.. everytime my login check get the 'e' character, convert that as '3' and then compare the hashed value from db.

Comment: @oxvoxic I was assuming that (using it on both register & login), however I would go with a proven encryption method (using for example using your custom password sting as an extra salt) for actual safe storage, and stick to removing leading/trailing spaces for your actual (unencrypted) password  
looks like a good example resource: https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm
(haven't used it but the examples look good on first glance)